# In mahout spectral clustering, what should be the diagonal element value in Affinity Matrix

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, data-mining, mahout

As the title tells everything, Here is the link to the spectral clustering [Spectral clustering Documentation](http://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/spectral-clustering.html)

The first step in it is extracting similarity matrix for our data points. When it says similarity matrix, I assume that the similarity between same entities(users, documents etc) should be 1( as opposed to distance matrix, where it is 0).

But in their example, they have assigned a score 0 for the same entities:

0,0 0

1,1 0

Here I am confused a bit. Could anyone, who worked on spectral clustering before help me out..

P.S.: I have my own approach to calculate similarity scores, So I don't want to use any in built mahout functions.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Consider *not* using Mahout. I do not have a lot of trust in that tool, in particular it seems to be really really slow. After I was able to beat the Mahout runtime on a single CPU with a better tool, I've pretty much given up on Mahout. Just because it runs on Hadoop doesn't mean it is good, or fast.

Comment: (But other than that, I believe you are correct, and the value should be 1, or whatever the kernel yields. If it is artificially set to 0, it should not be part of the output at all.)

Comment: Thanks Anony-Moousse. Actually testing the spectral clustering, with various seed values. Update the thread,once done with it

Answer (score 0):

I think we should see the similarity matrix as an extension of the adjacency matrix in graph theory: 1's if two nodes are adjacent, 0's if they are not. In your case, all the nodes are adjacent and you ponderate this adjancency matrix by a similarity matrix to encode the information about "how much two observations are adjancent ?".

Since we don't consider a node to be adjacent to itself unless it has a connection to itself, the diagonal of the adjacency matrix is set to 0.